# Sending ssh private key via form results in "asn1: syntax error: data truncated"

Tags: go, asn.1

I have a webform that allows a user to post a private key, hostname, username and it allows me to make a connection to "hostname" via ssh using the private key and run a test command.

I'm using golang and the ssh package for this test.

Yes, i am aware of the dangers of sending a private key over a form but this is an internal project for me and not something that will really be used publicly.

So, continuing on, here's what my code looks like

```
func setupSSHConfigWithKey(user string, pkey string) *ssh.ClientConfig {

pkey_bytes := []byte(pkey)

// parse the key
signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(pkey_bytes)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

When this piece of code runs, it results in the following error

> 2019/11/15 23:57:14 http: panic serving [::1]:62783: asn1: syntax error: data truncated

What's odd is that if i were to read my own "id_rsa.pub" using `io/ioutil`, the error doesn't occur. But only when i paste the contents of "id_rsa.pub" file does this error occur.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening and i'm not sure how to fix it.

I've checked the byte array output of the contents of the id_rsa.pub file as well as the form value and they are both identical and of the same length.

I suspect the error is coming from https://golang.org/src/encoding/asn1/asn1.go

so i'm trying to dive deeper into how to fix this but haven't come up with much so far.

Asking here to see how i can get around this error.

Edit:

This morning i've been researching some more and found some more interesting results

if i run the following code, i get no errors. But if i post the private key string below into a web form, and then use the same code below but with http request FormValue instead of just declaring a byte slice, i get the asn1 error denoted above. The below example is a test key.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "encoding/pem"
    "crypto/x509"
)

func main() {

    pkey_bytes := []byte(`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`)

    log.Println(pkey_bytes)

    block, _ := pem.Decode(pkey_bytes)
    log.Println("Block: " + block.Type)
    log.Println(block.Headers)
    log.Println(block.Bytes)
    _, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }   
}
```

output

> 2019/11/16 11:04:11 Block: RSA PRIVATE KEY 
>   2019/11/16 11:04:11 map[]
>   2019/11/16 11:04:11 [48 130 4 164 2 1 0 2 130 1 1 0 213 0 152 15 73
>   240 7 87 162 114 194 234 45 84 130 9 85 7 95 176 198 251 169 58 203
>   163 2 192 75 109 200 120 10 195 37 24 189 125 27 54 78 217 229 189 64
>   207 138 199 49 255 180 125 75 93 0 220 132 212 152 214 37 43 19 181
>   144 89 80 37 163 12 242 194 170 155 234 172 185 211 32 108 249 155 26
>   234 168 83 177 1 186 48 191 174 238 204 193 75 215 5 123 138 177 67 43
>   126 102 153 69 24 25 240 148 141 236 52 29 160 204 122 172 71 71 66 43
>   8 167 19 218 153 141 113 31 226 169 118 180 18 172 244 178 151 211 253
>   82 203 3 46 145 77 142 223 2 46 248 251 164 251 24 120 12 35 127 82 13
>   250 162 162 55 143 120 88 51 102 11 170 180 181 89 224 69 148 93 253
>   245 31 146 111 77 211 202 63 159 52 255 29 248 148 41 237 159 120 25
>   40 204 241 39 154 123 146 79 77 196 221 167 16 42 24 224 244 229 191 7
>   56 34 158 240 173 159 118 135 93 205 190 52 100 11 94 6 76 73 35 166
>   197 123 35 112 120 152 220 174 217 122 10 94 51 210 157 2 3 1 0 1 2
>   130 1 0 63 218 3 187 97 144 192 194 182 129 236 136 66 186 120 152 207
>   146 124 79 3 247 97 13 173 9 218 195 70 89 76 165 31 164 204 52 20 105
>   178 132 159 50 150 186 26 249 156 66 134 108 126 240 168 108 226 219
>   56 62 122 234 135 13 216 196 174 214 247 61 177 25 42 148 204 140 28
>   215 86 133 65 205 41 46 35 237 128 52 70 117 156 25 12 253 37 188 223
>   157 26 130 28 60 193 82 191 113 14 212 151 111 216 38 212 129 142 243
>   56 134 129 133 172 171 89 99 46 127 83 134 146 26 181 142 57 186 249
>   145 17 157 39 253 37 185 230 25 132 162 59 175 136 187 215 251 176 75
>   70 231 253 19 86 147 106 158 52 100 193 231 203 249 119 254 33 194 240
>   113 92 131 187 65 89 90 63 126 83 225 56 177 211 137 74 155 220 177
>   104 203 106 141 183 150 24 159 123 222 229 107 222 168 41 55 0 84 192
>   173 69 177 227 134 196 27 39 90 28 88 138 124 159 56 254 111 59 114
>   160 217 10 253 207 183 225 66 217 13 47 186 90 254 82 21 59 221 171
>   240 13 106 34 134 168 235 62 1 2 129 129 0 249 28 59 180 159 49 111
>   179 128 82 9 178 195 199 223 240 146 255 34 136 248 187 226 183 14 35
>   50 248 236 235 102 135 196 80 182 27 16 247 199 134 108 140 13 31 158
>   127 210 45 172 18 28 252 82 60 230 221 100 136 5 31 164 246 0 178 127
>   59 211 245 219 50 191 134 178 103 113 109 238 106 44 249 124 155 140
>   184 166 158 74 58 176 8 155 3 108 105 124 106 66 251 146 173 197 195
>   250 183 168 87 244 200 19 64 10 184 94 172 72 74 100 187 79 201 188 22
>   82 96 132 63 175 221 2 129 129 0 218 228 180 240 239 129 76 1 58 133
>   168 65 115 237 70 128 13 179 229 144 56 82 154 92 97 137 196 61 152 41
>   186 145 8 61 5 11 23 201 102 28 119 6 147 133 36 186 157 169 120 245
>   81 81 249 172 104 93 98 96 86 54 231 122 205 178 44 147 165 6 87 105
>   242 179 191 230 166 112 57 244 148 153 204 219 173 143 194 71 182 77
>   29 112 82 132 68 8 183 178 169 200 138 216 46 65 49 37 214 96 198 78
>   184 71 120 145 89 7 138 134 23 236 157 132 36 17 93 153 152 171 225
>   193 2 129 129 0 142 141 32 129 128 227 170 87 30 228 83 86 112 0 173
>   222 158 79 207 244 111 218 28 167 194 56 84 79 236 75 220 245 110 90
>   253 138 201 143 241 38 180 113 4 133 134 143 0 184 80 18 97 113 230
>   161 161 63 41 235 72 123 78 75 212 36 80 248 236 151 113 99 62 4 151
>   140 232 117 15 12 197 69 211 143 179 220 106 196 132 23 199 106 117 66
>   101 68 140 4 198 229 237 142 241 111 239 198 47 88 125 228 12 88 6 138
>   112 234 199 199 130 147 73 218 88 126 177 143 55 190 182 37 2 129 128
>   21 17 150 104 234 100 163 144 42 181 218 176 18 28 112 128 186 208 233
>   243 171 184 39 171 100 168 1 255 123 185 232 127 53 47 202 96 122 245
>   163 162 113 194 108 72 144 116 117 224 110 8 14 191 185 44 99 15 57
>   252 211 207 141 16 64 228 57 110 44 160 35 161 202 254 138 38 5 55 32
>   28 238 128 175 59 37 197 132 137 170 126 89 171 10 6 57 22 45 184 64
>   167 80 213 229 253 216 97 47 245 56 161 51 19 142 3 79 114 110 94 225
>   198 160 146 171 118 16 112 76 69 159 1 2 129 129 0 146 125 104 230 161
>   38 131 49 43 63 55 120 162 242 9 135 203 88 233 46 53 10 163 157 198
>   66 1 219 141 142 207 126 139 42 195 107 199 104 186 220 78 164 72 177
>   193 221 223 241 16 35 22 28 181 75 118 169 34 85 169 230 97 123 206 82
>   193 118 211 182 243 255 68 187 181 251 91 49 173 252 90 238 197 197
>   128 105 43 172 25 253 136 160 24 125 161 54 134 125 180 69 87 64 3 87
>   123 16 219 67 6 225 146 87 18 185 182 66 87 60 43 77 185 109 44 123 29
>   202 80 97 210 159]

Comment: Emmm, I'm a little confuesd why you input public key into function "ParsePrivateKey", it would be nice if you show some info about this ssh package.

Comment: @p1gd0g pkey is a string of the private key that I got from a webform.

Comment: If "pkey" is private key, why did you input "id_rsa.pub", which is a public key. That was what I am confused. RSA is non-symmetric crypto.

Answer (score 0):

> What's odd is that if i were to read my own "id_rsa.pub" using io/ioutil, the error doesn't occur. But only when i paste the contents of "id_rsa.pub" file does this error occur.

It is odd for me too, why you input "id_rsa.pub" (a public key) into `ssh.ParsePrivateKey`?

In my test, I input "id_rsa" (a private key) and no error occurs.

```golang
    pkbytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("id_rsa")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    s, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(pkbytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    log.Println(s.PublicKey())
```

So I guess if you know much about rsa, which is a non-symmetric cryptography, that means you can't transfer a public key into a private key (unless you have known the setup).

Or maybe you need to let us reproduce the error, or show how did you paste the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding posted data, since key may contains '=' chars at suffix.

Comment: Instead of adding "this should work..." as answers provide detailed answers that will actually provide an answer to the question.